# google adwords allows javascript in the ad?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

neither Google Adwords UI nor their API provides a function to add custom html for my ad creatives. but I would need javascript to, for example, fire a beacon when the ad is served. 
how can I insert an ad with javascript?

Comment: Being able to put arbitrary JavaScript into an ad seems like a security problem waiting to happen.

Comment: Couldn't you just use an image beacon?